# Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-web-roles

I'm trying to set up a WCF service hosted in a Windows Azure Web Role. I've configured the service for message security, so while using an unsecured channel, I want to encrypt the messages using a X509 certificate. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work on Azure. Locally I managed to set everything up correctly.

Here's the web.config of the WCF service:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=peterpan.cloudapp.net" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Skillconomy.Cloud.CheckInService.UserValidator, Skillconomy.Cloud.CheckInService" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I've configured the certificate in the Web Role:

[image]

And I've uploaded the certificate in the Azure portal:

[image]

I get the exception:

> Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search
>   criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType
>   'FindBySubjectName', FindValue 'CN=xyz.cloudapp.net'. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the
>   X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My',
>   StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue
>   'CN=xyz.cloudapp.net'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just as a suggestion - how about using the 'FindByThumbprint'. I've found the Subject can store other chunks of information that may break a direct string comparison.  If that fails, I would be tempted to RDP into the machine to ensure that the correct cert is uploading and into the correct location.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I've been working with FindByThumbprint originally and just switched to Subject afterwards because it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing:

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="CN=peterpan.cloudapp.net" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
```

to

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="CN=peterpan.cloudapp.net" />
```

Doesn't explain what was wrong exactly, but at least it works...

Answer (score 2):

if you are going to use x509FindType="FindBySubjectName", the findValue should be "peterpan.cloudapp.net" - without CN=